# Why during load grpc the module is impossible to find it?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to configure the libraries to be able to use php with firestore. Following the guide https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc I find a problem at the end after the exection of this command:

```
composer require "google/protobuf:^v3.3.0"
```

I receive this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\grpc.so' - Impossible to find specific module.
>   Problem 1 google/common-protos 0.1.0 requires google/protobuf ^3.6.1
>   -> satisfiable by google/protobuf[3.6.x-dev, 3.7.x-dev, v3.6.1, v3.6.1.1, v3.6.1.2, v3.6.1.3] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.

How can I figure out?

I'm working on XAmpp

Comment: There's no `composer require "google/protobuf:^v3.3.0"` on the linked site. Have you done `sudo pecl install grpc`?

Comment: Where does the `composer require` command occur? There seems to be a version conflict 3.3 / 3.6

Answer (score 0):

On Windows dynamically linked extensions have the file extension `.dll` instead of `.so` on iX systems. Respect this when adding the line `extension=grpc.so`, i.e. write `extension=grpc.dll` instead.

Check if the extension file exists in `C:\xampp\php\ext\`.

Comment: After that...I download the php_grcp.dll, renamed into grcp.dll and insert file into ext and rename the php.ini: that's the result: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - google/common-protos 0.1.0 requires google/protobuf ^3.6.1 -> satisfiable by google/protobuf[3.6.x-dev, 3.7.x-dev, v3.6.1, v3.6.1.1, v3.6.1.2, v3.6.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.